# Proguard makes my ConnectionService null

Tags: android, android-service, proguard, android-service-binding, android-proguard

I have a fragment that binds to a running service. So to bind I first declare a ConnectionService field as

```
private ServiceConnection mMyConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
         @Override     
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
             MyService.MyBinder binder = (MyService.MyBinder) service;
             mMyService = binder.getService();
             mMyBound = true;
             Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
             …     
    }
              @Override
         public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
             mMyBound = false;
         }
          };
```

And then inside `onCreate` I do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyService.class);     
getContext().bindService(intent, mMyConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

My Proguard-ed release build says that connection is null and crashes at the line `getContext().bindService(intent, mMyConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`. I am using

```
buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled true     
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
             zipAlignEnabled true
         }     
}
```

Comment: Do you use any parcelable objects?

Comment: if you mean do I extend parcelable then no.

Comment: try to exclude ServiceConnection/package that contains this class from proguard and see results

Comment: @pvllnspk I am using Proguard to obfuscate. So your solution is to not obfuscate. Well, then.